# Would this be divergenceless?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, differentiation, gauss-law, dipole

If I were to put two charges of opposing polarity next to each other (a finite distance away but not superimposed on each oter) and would then take the divergence of the whole $E$-field, would that be 0? But the local divergence would not be zero at the point charges, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "next to each other"?  Are they a finite distance $d$ away from each other, or are they superimposed on each other ("zero distance")?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert they are a finite distance away.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gauss's Law, the electric field is divergenceless ($\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$) at all points where $\rho =0$.  So that means that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ at all points except the points where the charges are located.

I'm not precisely sure what you mean by "local divergence".  But at the points where the charges are located, the charge density $\rho$ is infinite (there's a finite amount of charge in zero volume), and therefore so is the divergence of $\vec{E}$.  This can be dealt with in a mathematically formal way by something called the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), but the details of that are beyond the scope of this answer.

Finally, note that all of the above still holds true even if the point charges are both positive, and it still holds if there are more than two charges (or only one charge.)